# How to transform mouse coordinate using matrix?

Tags: c#, image-processing, matrix

I can get image coordinate using this code.But I want to do the same by using Matrix.

```
        private int _angle = 90;
        float scaleFactorX = (float)resizeWidth / (float)originalWidth;
        float scaleFactorY = (float)resizeHeight / (float)originalHeight;

        graphics.TranslateTransform((float)(width / 2), (float)(height / 2));
        graphics.ScaleTransform(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        graphics.RotateTransform(_angle);
        graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)originalWidth / 2, -(float)originalHeight /2);
        graphics.TransformPoints(System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CoordinateSpace.World, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CoordinateSpace.Device, point);
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [Graphics.MultiplyTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt34tx5d.aspx) were you pass [Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.aspx) type instance.

Matrix type has a methods for aplying tranformation to it:

```
Matrix mx = new Matrix();
```

[Rotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7dwd0wc.aspx)

[Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/866h97eh.aspx)

[Translate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31bey05a.aspx)

I would suggest to follow this order and not make translation first, as it's easy to be messed up with rotation center and rotation axis in those cases.

Comment: @Shikha: anda fter apply resulting matrix to  the graphics object itself

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite useful resource, when you can learn how to transform coordinates using matrices. You need operation: translate, rotate - and they're also good described.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536397%28VS.85%29.aspx